# Ada use of aspect Default_Component_Value on an array, with Pragma Pack

Tags: ada

I'm using gnat gcc 11.1, and wanted to know if someone can explain to me this behavior:

This is my code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;           use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
pragma Ada2012;

procedure Hello is
   type bool_arr is array (Integer range 1 .. Integer'Size) of Boolean with
      Default_Component_Value => True;
   pragma Pack (bool_arr);

   test : bool_arr;

   procedure P is
      idx   : String           := "index ";
      strg  : Unbounded_String := To_Unbounded_String (idx);
      strg2 : Unbounded_String;
   begin
      for I in test'range loop
         Append (strg, I'Image);
         Append (strg2, " " & test (I)'Image);
      end loop;
      Put_Line (To_string (strg));
      Put_Line (To_String (strg2));

   end P;
begin
   P;
end Hello;
```

As Out I get this :

> Hello, world! index  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
> 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

Which is not what I wanted, by setting `with Default_Component_Value => True`.

If I comment out the `Pragma Pack(bool_arr)`, then I get this:

> > Hello, world! index  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
> > TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
> > TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Specifying `Component_Size => 1` has the same bad effect.  Compiling with an optimisation level greater than 0 makes all the values `False`! which is at least consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a bug in GNAT, I'm sorry to say.

If I explicitly use the Default_Component_Value, by declaring

```
   test : bool_arr := (others => <>);
```

all components are True, as expected.

Comment: I'm actually fixing a problem right now where that ended up causing an issue.  The boolean ended up being "neither True or False" and threw an exception when the message being populated was sent to Java.  Using Default_Component_Value fixed the issue.  Oddly Ada was still very happy.  If I printed out the value it was True/False.  If you dumped the hex it was "74".  Took us forever to find.